# Best way to add custom buttons in UITableViewCell if the TableViewCell have a lot of data to show. using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

i am trying to know the best way to add custom buttons in UITableViewCell if we have a lot of data to show. I know about `cell.button.tag = indexPath.row` method to get the indexPath of button, but if there's much more data in the `tableViewCell` things get messed up using `tag` if i set the title to be changed when tapped some other cell's button title also changes automatically.. I've been finding a solution from 2-3 weeks.. Help me out here please. Thanks for your time. A nice tutorial or explanation would do best. Because I'am a beginner..

Comment: Why not use a custom cell subclass? Each would have its own button property, and you wouldn't need to mess about with `tag` which is really archaic.

Comment: can you provide me a link/explanation for that?

Comment: The internet is littered with good examples, try googling "custom UITableViewCell".

Answer (score 4):

This is likely too late to help you, but in case someone else needs to be pointed in the right direction:

This [tutorial](http://candycode.io/how-to-properly-do-buttons-in-table-view-cells/) has a quick rundown on implementing buttons in custom table view cells using the delegate method. Good luck!

Quick edit:
The accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29913066/how-to-access-the-content-of-a-custom-cell-in-swift-using-button-tag) does a good job of explaining it clearly as well.