# Swift Button inside CustomCell (TableView) passing arguments to targetMethod

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, tableview, custom-cell

My `TableView` features custom Cells which have a button to display corresponding detailed info in another view. 
This thread here got me started and I tried to implement the approach with the delegate inside the `customCell`:
[How to access the content of a custom cell in swift using button tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29913066/how-to-access-the-content-of-a-custom-cell-in-swift-using-button-tag)

What I want to achieve is that when I click on the button it reads the name of the cell and passes it on to the next controller. However it seems that I cannot pass the name with the delegate method and its field is `nil`.

How can I get the specific content of a cell when clicking on its button?

This is what I did so far:

In the class creating my own cell I set delegate:

```
protocol CustomCellDelegate {
 func cellButtonTapped(cell: DemoCell)
}
(........)
 var delegate: CustomCellDelegate?

@IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    delegate?.cellButtonTapped(self)
}
```

In the `TableViewController` I have the following:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath
    indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell =
        tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FoldingCell",
                                                    forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DemoCell
    cell.delegate = self

 //TODO: set all custom cell properties here (retrieve JSON and set in cell), use indexPath.row as arraypointer

    let resultList = self.items["result"] as! [[String: AnyObject]]
    let itemForThisRow = resultList[indexPath.row]

    cell.schoolNameClosedCell.text = itemForThisRow["name"] as! String
    cell.schoolNameOpenedCell.text = itemForThisRow["name"] as! String

    self.schoolIdHelperField = itemForThisRow["name"] as! String

    cell.schoolIntroText.text = itemForThisRow["name"] as! String

  //call method when button inside cell is tapped
    cell.innerCellButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MainTableViewController.cellButtonTapped(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    cell.school_id = itemForThisRow["name"] as! String

  //  cell.schoolIntroText.text = "We from xx University..."
    return cell
}
```

And finally the target method when the button inside the cell is clicked

```
func cellButtonTapped(cell: DemoCell) {
    print("the school id: ")
    print(cell.schoolNameOpenedCell) //this line throws an error EXC_BAD_ACCESS 0x0

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, the object ***innerCellButton*** is not a Cell, it's a button. The simple way to solve your problem is, just refer the index of the button. Please find the below method.

```
func cellButtonTapped(AnyObject: sender) {

  let resultList = self.items["result"] as! [[String: AnyObject]]
  //Get the tag value of the selected button. 
  //Button tag should be matching with the corresponding cell's indexpath.row
  let selectedIndex = sender.tag
  let itemForThisRow = resultList[selectedIndex]
  print("the school id: \(itemForThisRow[\"name\"])")

}
```

*** And set each button's tag as indexPath.row ***

E.g.,

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath
indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

// Dequeue your cell and other code goes here.

// set the button's tag like below.
cell.innerCellButton.tag = indexPath.row
return cell
}
```

Comment: Thx, this is working well. I had to change the protocol signature: protocol CustomCellDelegate {
 func cellButtonTapped(cell: DemoCell)  to (sender: AnyObject)
}
and func cellButtonTapped(AnyObject: sender) to func cellButtonTapped( sender: AnyObject)

Answer (score 0):

Close. I wouldn't use Suresh's method since it does not help find the IndexPath, which includes section and row.

First, I would recommend a model object for your table view data source. Learn more about the MVC pattern as well as parsing a JSON response to an object with mapping. However, this would give you the data you want.

```
func cellButtonTapped(cell: UITableViewCell) {
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)
    let resultList = self.items["result"] as! [[String: AnyObject]]
    let itemForThisRow = resultList[indexPath.row]
    let name = itemForThisRow["name"] as! String
}
```

Comment: Thx, but I got a nil value for indexPath here. Sureshs method worked after some minor changes however so I go with that

Comment: DemoCell should be UITableViewCell for my method to work. (Remove the subclass parameter) @user2039697