# Using delegate and protocol I can't able to access function inside the UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, swift-protocols

I want to show/hide collection view inside the table view's check button selection

I am trying to use delegate and protocol for that.

1.I create protocol in table view cell class

```
   protocol CustomCellDelegate{
   func selectCollectionView(cell: InsideTableViewCell)
   }
```

Note:I create selectCollectionView function inside the main view controller

2.declare delegate variable inside the main view class

```
var delegate: CustomCellDelegate?
```

3.Confirm to the CustomCellDelegate in the main class

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,CustomCellDelegate
```

4.Use selector function to provide table view button inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath function

```
cell.checkButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.selectCheck(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
cell.delegate = self
```

5.Selector function

```
 @objc func selectCheck(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if sender.isSelected {
        sender.isSelected = false
        print("Check 1")

    delegate?.selectCollectionView(cell: InsideTableViewCell)

    } else{
        print("Check 2")
        sender.isSelected = true

    }


}
```

6.selectCollectionView function

```
func selectCollectionView(cell: InsideTableViewCell) {

    cell.clCollectionView.isHidden = true
}
```

I am trying to call selectCollectionView function inside the selectCheck button

but I get error like "Cannot convert value of type 'InsideTableViewCell.Type' to expected argument type 'InsideTableViewCell'"

If I do mistake please let me know.

I referred this link:[How to access the content of a custom cell in swift using button tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29913066/how-to-access-the-content-of-a-custom-cell-in-swift-using-button-tag?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

And Screenshot of output:

[image]

Comment: Change `delegate?.selectCollectionView(cell: InsideTableViewCell)` to `delegate?.selectCollectionView(cell: anActualCell)`

Comment: Not relsolved using InsideTableViewCell @matt this is actual cell I tried with self also but still getting same error

Comment: The issue is that `InsideTableViewCell`is a class, not an object. You need to retrieve the cell (object) in that method. `self` won't work in your case because it's a `ViewController` object. put the selector code inside the cell.swift code and it then you can use `self` correctly. Just set the delegate to the viewcontroller.

Comment: @Larme reloved the issue.Thank you so much.